# Do you need free hands to cast a spell?

Tags: spellcasting, dungeon-crawl-classics-rpg

In Dungeon Crawl Classics do you need free hands to cast a spell? This came up in one of my most recent play sessions for both wizards and clerics. It seems a bit more important in this system as it takes a full action to pull something out of a pack or stow it away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DCC is light on minutiae like this (at least in the core book which I am using as a source) and I was unable to find any references to the number of hands needed to cast a spell, so in the end the decision will come down to Judge's preference. But by observing the art in the book we can make a spirited guess at what answer the designers might have used at their table. Recall that DCC was meant to emulate pulp fantasy more than simulate a fictional reality!

Thumbing through the core book we see that many wizards are depicted utilizing both hands in order to cast spells. Where they are not depicted utilizing both hands they often possess a stave or wand in one hand while gesturing with the other. Thus one hand is sufficient to gesture, channel energies, or otherwise 'do magic'. The other may be occupied by a staff, torch, or sword (or in the case of page 238 - a dagger). I was unable to find any art showing a wizard casting spells while both hands are occupied with non-spellcasting implements (ie a sword and torch). But as pages 231 and 108 demonstrate both hands can be occupied while spellcasting - provided they're occupied with the spell being cast. Instead of gesturing, pointing, and touching, they are bloodletting, writing runes, and more.

To condense:

**While no explicit answer is given within the text, the approved art in the core book suggests that wizards require a minimum of one free hand to cast spells, and that many or even all spells can be cast this way. *If* both the wizard's hands are occupied, they must be occupied as part of the spellcasting process, such as by manipulating foci or magical tools, in order to cast a spell and not as part of non-spellcasting activity.**

Note that I feel this conclusion can only be firmly reached for wizards and quite possibly elves ("arcane casters"). Clerics are often treated differently in both tabletop games and other media, and are often depicted as able to readily cast spells (or otherwise wield divine power) not only while armor-clad but through a holy symbol or raised weapon as opposed to solely through a gesturing hand. The art in the book does not clarify this issue; showing firmly-held holy symbols or weapons shining with power in one depiction and gestures causing magical effects the next.